# PySpark - How to filter dates with OR clause?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I need to create a PySpark script that, among other conditions and filters, queries a given table to look for rows either after a given date OR another. This is how my code looks:

```py
#imports
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, collect_list
from datetime import date

...

hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
today = str(date.today())
date_filter_condition = (col("created") >= today) | (col("updated") >= today)

lookup = hive_context.table("MY_TABLE").filter(col("status") == 1 & date_filter_condition)
```

The above code throws an error:

> An error occurred while calling o365.and. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

If I remove the part that includes the dates filter ("& date_filter_condition") the script works just fine. How to properly filter dates using pySpark? I'm using the date in the following format YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the actual condition in the filter function instead of assigning it to a variable.

```
lookup = hive_context.table("MY_TABLE").filter((col("status") == 1) & (col("created") >= today) | (col("updated") >= today))
```

See [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your suggestion and got the same error message. Do I need to convert the dates before making the comparison?

Comment: Update: your suggestion did fix the issue! But it was not only putting the condition in the filter, I also had to put both conditions between parenthesis. Thank you so much!